# Alert error message in $.when.apply()

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function as `$.when.apply($,fn).then(function(){ alert('success') });`

This `alert('success')` will trigger when all **fn[ ] are success**. Otherwise it will not trigger the success alert. In this case (when all **fn[ ] are not success**) i need to show `alert('error')`. How can i achieve this..?

Comment: `$.when.apply($,fn).then(function(){ alert('success') },function(){alert('error')});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass An optional function that is called when the Deferred is rejected

```
$.when.apply($,fn).then(function(){ alert('success') }, function(){ alert('error') })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fail` and `done` instead of then

```
var promise = $.when.apply($,fn)
promise.done(function() { alert('done') });
promise.fail(function(){ alert('error') });
```

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/